# AWS Elastic beanstalk - My deployed app can't seem to write pdf's into this directory i've set up in my project folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using nodejs that is deployed in ebs on aws. I have a function that will write a pdf and then email it off but it says the file path can't be found. I've verified the project file seems to be /var/app/current/, but changing the reference of the file path doesn't seem to remove the error. Any idea how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `/var/app/current/` does not exist initially. Its only created at the very last stage of your deployment.

The deployment happens in `/var/app/staging/` folder, and at the very last, once everything finishes, `/var/app/staging/` is moved into `/var/app/current/`.

Thus, I would not recommend using absolute paths in your project or config files. Its better to use relative path or [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) for config scripts:

> The specified commands run as the root user, and are processed in alphabetical order by name. Container commands are **run from the staging directory**, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server.

Comment: I'm using functions like fs.writeFile, can that be done through relative paths or with container commands?

Comment: @scotth527 Hi. Try relative paths. Container commands would be used in your ebextentions.